# what about the ODR rule for specialization that instantiated from a template

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, language-lawyer

```cpp
//Tpl.h
template<typename T>
void show(T){
}
```

```cpp
// a translate unit
#include "Tpl.h"
void h(){
  show(0);  //implicitly instantiate specialization for show<int>
}
```

```cpp
// b translate unit
#include "Tpl.h"
int main(){
  show(0);  //implicitly instantiate specialization for show<int>
}
```

According to rules in [temp.inst], there is a specialization for function template `show` in `a` and `b` translate unit respectively, that means there're two same specializations in a program.

However, the `ODR` rule does not mention this case.
[basic.def.odr#6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.def.odr#6)

> **There can be more than one definition** of a class type, enumeration type, inline function with external linkage ([dcl.inline]), inline variable with external linkage ([dcl.inline]), class template, non-static function template, static data member of a class template, member function of a class template, or template specialization for which some template parameters are not specified ([temp.spec], [temp.class.spec]) in **a program** provided that each definition appears in a different translation unit, and provided the definitions satisfy the following requirements. Given such an entity named D defined in more than one translation unit, then

The case the rule listed are the following:

> - class type
> - enumeration type
> - inline function or inline variable
> - class template
> - non-static function template
> - static data member of a class template
> - member function of a class template
> - template specialization for which some template parameters are not specified

So, how about `function template` or `static member function template` ?

It also doesn't cover the case that exists more than one same specializations for a template in a program, the last item in the above list seems to refer to `template partial specializations`,  So Is it a defect? Or there're other special rules applied to this case?

Comment: For explicit instantiations, there's this: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.spec#temp.explicit-5. I didn't find anything on implicit instantiations, but if the explicit instantiation is required in every translation unit, I assume the implicit one is not a problem.

Comment: @BennyK  Thanks for your link, however it just an inference about implicit instantiation, there's no quote about implicit instantiation whether the definition from such instantiation can present in each translate unit, I think it could be mentioned in [basic.def.ord], however it doesn't actually. Maybe other language-lawyer gurus have the answers.

Comment: I think it's worth keeping in mind that "definition" in this paragraph is in the sense of https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.def - it does not include implicit instantiation (those don't come from declarations even).

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Maybe It's the reason why [basic.def.odr] section does not mention this, however in [temp.inst#4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.inst#4), It seems to imply that a `definition` would be generated from the template.

Comment: Not a definition in the normative sense, I'd say. It more implies than an instantiation creates an entity. Obviously a compiler must emit the function somewhere. But it's not the translated program that defines this function (which is how a "definition" is defined). The ODR deals in stuff **we** write, and must mean the same thing across TUs. I don't think it applies to stuff a compiler emits as part of its operation. Anyway, that's my working theory.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Ok, then how about function template or static member function template or static data member template, It should be the definition we write in the code, it should be a normative definition, however the rule does not mention them.

Comment: That is a good point. And I think there may be a defect reported somewhere about this, because the latest standard draft mentions "templated entity" http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#13.4 - the things you noted are included there

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Oh, that will cover all kinds of template, Right? In addition, that's [CWG2433](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1968r0.html#2433)

Comment: Yeah, that will cover a whole lot more

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica But, how to interpret the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62789153/what-about-the-odr-rule-for-specialization-that-instantiated-from-a-template?noredirect=1#comment111037946_62789153) `@BennyK` mentioned, It seems to an addition to ord-rule

Comment: An explicit instantiation is a declaration (and a definition under basic.def), that's true. And there cannot be more than one such definition in a program. So there's no contradiction.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica It seems to my misunderstanding, even though the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62789153/what-about-the-odr-rule-for-specialization-that-instantiated-from-a-template?noredirect=1#comment111037946_62789153) `@BennyK` mentioned, It still cover the definition of template we write in the translate unit, Right?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. And honestly I don't know what Benny had in mind when bringing that paragraph up. It doesn't seem at all related to the ODR.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica What I mean is that, the rule says that as if in translate unit `A`, firstly include `Tpl.h` then write explicitly instantiation `template void show(int);`, do the same things in translate unit `B`, that's what the rule means, Right?

Comment: If you do `template void show(int)` in two translation units, that's two definitions (in the normative sense). That's simply not allowed.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica The declaration `template void show(int)` is not a definition ,due to [basic.def#2.17](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.def#2.17), So it doesn't violate the odr-rule even if exists more than one such entity in a program.

Comment: It is a definition. It is a declaration (check the grammar), and "a declaration is a definition unless..." and none of the bullets apply. It says "explicit instantiation declaration" - that's a normative term. It means `extern template void show(int)`.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica The link `BennyK` mentioned only means if we want to explicitly instantiate a template, the definition of such template should be present in every translate unit where such explicitly instantiate appears. So, I say I misunderstood that sentence before.

Comment: The key here is that in the link Benny mentioned "explicit instantation" is used for both its meanings. "explicit instantiation declaration" and "explicit instantiation definition". Both of those require the template to be present. But a definition can still only appear in a single TU.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica The keyword `extern` is opt ,[temp.explicit#2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.explicit#2)

Comment: Of course it's optional. When it's present the thing is a declaration. When it's not the thing is a definition.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica  Oh, thanks. it's my mistake, you mean `template void show(int)`  is a definition, so , if it exists in more than one TU, then it would violate the ODR, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You got me.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Thanks. In addition, if  a explicit specialization appears in more than one TUS, it also violate ODR? I'm not sure class template partial specialization would be, it seems to be a template and is the exception of ODR.